# Centos Java Application Killed Automatically

Tags: java, linux, centos, kill, shutdown

On my centos node, after starting the application in terminal with a command (sh run.sh), a few things are loaded and printed out to, and then I receive this line of text:

```
run.sh: line 1: 32366 Killed                  java -Xmx1024m -Xss2m -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500 -XX:SurvivorRatio=16 -XX:+UseParallelGC -classpath bin:data/libs/* com.sallesy.Application
```

The text after the "Killed" is everything that is contained in my shell script.

Why is this happening? How do I fix it?

Comment: how much memory is available on the box?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some error logging and research, the answer to my question is that the node did not have enough memory available.